# Docker file with git installation for windows

Tags: python, git, powershell, docker, dockerfile

I need to create a docker file that does the following:

Install python.

Install git.

Clone git repo.

Run with latest commit.

I have the following for linux:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python-pip
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python-setuptools
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python-wheel
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git

# Clone project github repository
WORKDIR /repo
RUN git clone https://github.com/<repo>.git
# Checkout version 
WORKDIR /repo/project
RUN git checkout <latest commit>
```

In the windows docker file creation I'll skip python installation by using `python:2.7-windowsservercore-1809` as the base image.

I tried to search online for ways to install git like the above in linux, but couldn't find any way that worked for me (like using chocolaty)

Any ideas how to create an equivalent docker file for windows container?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker%5D+install+git+windows

Comment: https://chocolatey.org/packages/git.install